# .htaccess image folder redirect from other server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

So I need to do a .htaccess file that allow me to redirect the images link folder (wp-content/upload/) from a different site (http://widesigner.com.br/alessandra/) to be this one (http://www.alessandratonisi.com.br/site/)

Basically it's redirect some image links, example:

```
http://www.widesigner.com.br/alessandra/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/MG_6058-600x400.jpg
http://www.widesigner.com.br/alessandra/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/MG_9515.jpg
```

to

```
http://www.alessandratonisi.com.br/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/MG_6058-600x400.jpg
http://www.alessandratonisi.com.br/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/MG_9515.jpg
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer your own question to add info. You need to edit your question and add the info there.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is redirect a website domain to another one for a specific folder. I don't know if the next line will help you to solve the problem, I don't think that will be the solution since I didn't test it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/alessandra/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.alessandratonisi.com.br/site/%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Here are a lot of examples that could lead you to the correct answer: https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489.

**UPDATE:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/alessandra/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.alessandratonisi.com.br/site/%1 [R=302,NC]

RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think because the old server is **/alessandra** and the new server is **/site/**.

Comment: @BrunoAlves I just edited the answer, should work now :D

Comment: I try, but nothing happens, If you can, see my answer

Comment: @BrunoAlves try with the updated code, I put the condition first, but that shouldn't affect theoretically, perhaps I'm missing something. That should work I think.

Comment: For a while I thought it would work, but didn't . Also put condition first , It changed nothing.
I'd Trying a diffenret code `RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://alessandratonisi.com.br/site/$1 [L]` but that was unsuccessful